# How to get module list with Netbeans Java CVS Client library

Tags: java, cvs

I'm using the Netbeans Java CVS Client library to access CVS and wanted to autodiscover existing modules.
(Note: when i say modules, i don't mean CVS modules in CVSROOT, i mean folders in the repository root.)

Setting `CheckoutCommand.setShowModules(true)` seems to look for the CVS modules and in my case returns nothing.

How do i get a list of the root folders without having to do a full checkout?

Comment: Here's what i did:
I'm using CheckoutCommand with setPipeToOutput(true), i.e. text output, and parse the response.

That is not very fast because i have to filter through all files.

Comment: More information please